# Switching even- and odd-indexed characters in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab, write a function called tripFlip that takes in one string and switches each even-indexed charactar with the odd-indexed character immediately preceding it. Use iteration.  Example: `tripFlip('orange')` ->`'ronaeg'`

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is homework, so I won't give a complete answer.  You can use `double` to convert a string to an array, and `char` to go back, if working with arrays makes the problem any easier.  Otherwise, strings seem to work just like arrays in terms of indexing: `s(1)` gets the first character, `length(s)` gets the length, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree its a homework question, and posting it here will only bite you back in the long run.  But here goes:

```
a = 'orange';
b = '';
b(2:2:length(a))= a(1:2:end);
b(1:2:length(a))= a(2:2:end);

disp(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
>> input = 'orange';
>> output = input(reshape([2:2:end;1:2:end],1,[]))
output =
ronaeg
```

It's not a function and doesn't use iteration, but it's how you'd solve this if you were to learn Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, perhaps you want to make it a bit more robust.

```
function b = TripFlip(a)
a = 'orange';
b = '';
for i  = 2:2:length(a)
    b=[b a(i) a(i-1)]
end
```